# Android - Detect Collision of random imageviews

Tags: android, collision, detection

as the title says, I am randomly create and move imageviews in my app.
Now i want to get a toast-message if two of them intersect. ( The best case would be if i could toast the Imageview-names,but its not necessary ).

Thank you so far,
Dennis

Comment: How much imageviews do you have? If you have plenty of them i would highly suggest you to either use box2d otherwise have a look at this http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game6.html

Comment: @avk i tried this  Rect rc1 = new Rect();
        firstIV.getHitRect(rc1);
        Rect rc2 = new Rect();
        secondIV.getHitRect(rc2);

Comment: @A.S. Yes they continue spawning every 1,5 seconds

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's always worth a try, to do it on your own. But if you want a fast progress and want to make games in the future, learn how to use physics libraries like box2d.